# How and where to write a logic to append strings at the end of an external link in WordPress blog posts

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am a noob. I have recently started a blog on WordPress, say http://www.example.com. I wrote a script for all clean external links (https://www.external.com) to get converted into "http://www.example.com/links?https://www.external.com". Now, I want to write a custom logic to append different strings at end of external link depending on what this external link is. Where and how to do it?

Custom code written for external links to get converted:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = 0; i< links.length; i++){

  if(links[i].href.indexOf("example.com") == -1)
  {
    links[i].href = "http://www.example.com/link?" + links[i].href;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Where - obviously there where you are already setting the new href for the links. How - keep the data you want to append in an object, using the domain as key/property name, and what you want to append as the value. Then check if an entry for the domain of the current URL you are dealing with exists in that object, and if so, append it …

Comment: Your question is still incomplete. Can you add an example of what you finally want to achieve?

Comment: @misorude currently i have added this script in header.php. But i can't write the logic there as then page rendering will take a lot of time.

Comment: @zipkundan example : external link on my site can be "https://www.external1.com" or "https://www.external2.com". Now i have already added a script for these external links to get converted to "http://www.example.com/links?https://www.external1.com" and "http://www.example.com/links?https://www.external2.com" respectively. Now, I want "http://www.example.com/links?https://www.external1.com" to get converted to  "https://www.external1.com/id=1" and  "http://www.example.com/links?https://www.external2.com" to get converted to "https://www.external2.com/id=5"

Comment: What is the correlation between the id number and the external link? Is it the sequence they appear on the page?

Comment: @zipkundan No. there is no sequence. it is just an example. I want to fetch the external link and on the basis of external link i want to append a manually inputted string. like if the external link is external1 i want to append "string1" which has certain value that i'll input and if the link is external2, i'll append some "string2".

Comment: How and where are you going to input the string manually? And if you are going to input the string manually, which do you want to write a script for that, you do that manually.

Comment: i'll write it in the script. I just need to put 2 else if conditions for 2 external links and i'll define the appending string manually for those 2 only. for rest i dont want to append anything. so whenever clean link of those 2 external link is posted..they get appended with my already defined strings.